# Custom shape with border in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container, and I want it to have a custom border like the image below. I found ClipPath, which gave me the shape I wanted, but it doesn't provide the border. I also found ShapeBorder, but I don't know how to deal with it. My question is, "How do I make this shape with a border in a professional way?

[image]

Comment: professional way? use custom `ShapeBorder` (or even better `OutlinedBorder`), check the sources of existing implementations for more info (like `CircleBorder`) - other implementers are: 
BeveledRectangleBorder, ContinuousRectangleBorder, MaterialStateOutlinedBorder, RoundedRectangleBorder and StadiumBorder

Comment: but you could also use this simplified border class: [PathBuilderBorder](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L126) - check the examples below on how to use it

Comment: @pskink I will check it , special thank to you .